# Best practice for saving one section of text (e-mail) that administrators can edit

Tags: email

I have a custom form that takes the input, sends it to a webservice, which then creates a user and sends an e-mail to the new user.

However, the e-mail text will from time to time be changed. My question is, where should I store this text so that changes to it are stored permanently (so users don't have to change it every time they visit the form) while still allowing easy access to edit it (via SP)?

I though of simply using a list, but this is the only piece of text I need stored so it seemed a bit over the top.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place under my opinion would be a SharePoint list as you yourself have indicated, because you need the text to be configurable at any point along with the ease to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the info in a list, you could also do something similar to this: http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/12/01/quick-dirty-sharepoint-email-templates/